# Building a job recommendation system

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I am building a job recommendation system where in i have the required skills for each role along with the value of the skill relevant for the role. Example of the dataset is as shown in the image. What would be the best approach to build a recommendation engine where a user inputs his skills and we have to recommend a role to him.

[image: Dataset]